# I deleted Webapp without starting and stopping the server

Tags: tomcat

I deleted a Tomcat Webapp without starting and stopping the server,
and now when I try to start tomcat again, it gives me an error:

```
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: no my directory var/lib/tomcat7/log is not there anymore what do I do?

Comment: Did you check, do you still have a directory `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs/`?  Could it be that you deleted that along with the webapp? If it's still there, check the permissions on that folder

Comment: No, my directory var/lib/tomcat7/log is not there anymore, what do I do?

Comment: How do I create it, just add a new folder?, do I need to put any files in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the directory (with [mkdir](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir)):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/
```